# Android change Opacity of some items in ItemizedOverlay

Tags: java, android, google-maps, itemizedoverlay

I'm trying to change the alpha-channel of some `OverlayItems` in an `ItemizedOverlay`. The `ItemizedOverlay` is added to a MapView in Android.

If I use this code, **all** items have the same opacity.
According to the logs the condition hits in about 50%...

Any ideas? It doesn't help if I override the `getMarker()` method in the `OverlayItem` either. It's the same effect.

This approach **does** work if I use 2 different drawables (1 for each case)... but I need to use the same drawable.

```
for (OverlayItem overlay : overlays) {              
    Drawable marker = boundCenterBottom(context.getResources().getDrawable(markerId));
    if (/* some condition - about 50/50 */) {           
        marker.setAlpha(100);
        Log.d("itemized Overlay", "FILTER set marker to => " + marker);
    } else {
        Log.d("itemized Overlay", "NOFILT set marker to => " + marker);
    }

    overlay.setMarker(marker);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `mutate()` on the `Drawable` instance, because otherwise it will share the state.

Like said in the documentation of mutate():

> [...] A
>   mutable drawable is guaranteed to not share its state with any other
>   drawable. This is especially useful when you need to modify properties
>   of drawables loaded from resources. By default, all drawables
>   instances loaded from the same resource share a common state; if you
>   modify the state of one instance, all the other instances will receive
>   the same modification. [...]

Pretty simple, it works this way:

```
for (OverlayItem overlay : overlays) {              
    Drawable marker = boundCenterBottom(context.getResources().getDrawable(markerId));
    marker.mutate();
    if (/* some condition */) {           
        marker.setAlpha(100);
    }

    overlay.setMarker(marker);
}
```